# Looking to change the background color on a gantt chart using data passed from the model

Tags: javascript, html

I am looking to change the colors of the gantt chart based on the data coming from the model.

```
style="background-color: #= JobColor #">
```

Where JobColor could be one of several different hex codes found in my database.

Comment: You need to provide more of the code. Since you tagged JavaScript I'm guessing that's what you want to use, do you have jQuery? If not, does the DOM element whose color you want to change has a title? Show the model too, please. We can't help you if you don't give us information.

Comment: I have discovered that even though it is telling me there is an error with this, it will actually make the changes.  I had to restart Visual Studios to make it work.  Thank you for responding.  I will post more code showing what works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the complete code for the template modifications, including turning it red when completed.

```
  <script id="task-template" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    # if (percentComplete < 1) { #
    <div class="template" style="background-color: #= JobColor # ">

        <div class="wrapper">
            <span class="resource" style="font-size:smaller">#= City #, #=State#</span>
            @*<strong class="title">#= title # </strong>
            <span class="resource">#=ContactName#</span>
            <span class="resource">#=Phone#</span>*@

        </div>
    </div>
    # } else { #
    <div class="template" style="background-color: red;">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <strong class="title">#= title # </strong>
            <span class="resource">Job is complete</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    # } #
</script>
```

There was no extra code in the controller, just this little bit of code to the task view along with adding the method to the model.

```
          TaskViewModel task = new TaskViewModel();
                task.TaskID = taskId;
                task.ParentID = null;
                task.Id = job.Id;
                task.Title = team.Id;
                task.ContactName = job.ContactName;
                task.Phone = job.Phone;
                task.City = job.City;
                task.State = job.State;
                task.JobType = job.JobTypeId;
                task.Start = job.PlanStartDate;
                task.End = job.PlanEndDate;
                task.JobColor = job.JobColor;
                task.Expanded =true;
                task.Summary = false;
```

The error was stating that the original code is not a valid color, which is true and the colors didn't change until after reloading the program.